# Installing docker in windows 8.1 64 bit operating system?

Tags: windows, docker, virtualization

I'am trying to install docker toolbox in windows 8.1 64 bit operating system. When I try to open it after installing it throws error like

```
        Running pre-create checks...
        Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: @KenTucker Intel B960

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately Intel B960 does not meet the system requirments needed for hyper-v a requirment for docker for windows.

Take a look at Docker Toolbox  which is for older Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of Docker for Windows.

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/